# How to create a test facebook page for testing chatbot

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-chatbot

I am developing a **chatbot** for **facebook messenger platform** using wit.ai.

I created a facebook page to test the bot but the page is visible to everyone. Is there a way that i can have my facebook page visible only for me and the testers i add to **developers.facebook.com**? 
I tried unpublishing the page in facebook but if i do that, the page is not visible even for my account when i search in **messenger platform**.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes after unpublishing, it doesn't show up in messenger search. But you can always initiate conversation from FB page and then it'll appear in your chats. For testing, you can add the testers as editors by going to page roles under settings in your page. Also remember to add them as testers in your app.

Comment: Whats wrong with having the page be public? All of my test pages are public, but it doesn't matter as the only people who have access to the bot are who I choose to have access.

Comment: Agreed with user2322082...never really an issue